# How to make a custom long press menu in recyclerview item

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a recyclerview, in this recyclerview I have a lot of cardviews with information. I need to make that when the user makes a long press in one of the cards in the recyclerviews. The menu should look like this, with the rounded corners and the icons.
[image]

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**
I have tried Making a context menu, this didn't worked because the icons and the rounded corners didn't appeared. I have also tried with a popup menu, this didn't work either. The current thing I have, is that I made a layout based on a Recyclerview, changing its position and visibility when a long touch ocurres; this didn't worked as expected, so that's why I am here. I'm trying to make this inside my ViewHolder of my CardAdapter, so I can use the OnLongPressed event.